# CI: Select max return integer?

Tags: codeigniter

I think I've not found this answer on stackoverflow. I've need codeigniter function that will return me 0 if table is empty and max int from table if there is some data.

**songs(IDSon, title)**

I've tried with:

```
    $this->db->select_max('IDSon');
    $query = $this->db->get('songs');
```

But how can I access "IDSon" field, and to add IF clause if table is empty to get 0?

Thanks

Comment: max will be in ['IDSon']. set 0 if it false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_max_number() {
    $result = $this->db->select_max('IDSon')->get('songs')->result_array();
    return (int) $result[0]['IDSon'];
}
```